# Usage: godaddy bot.py [-h] domain godaddy bot.py: error: the following arguments are required: domain

Tags: python, argparse, godaddy-api

I was writing a code for a domains availability checker and when I run the code it gives me an error so I hope anyone knows the solution of it because it's a coding summer camp project and I should submit it in those few days.

The code:

```
import argparse
import time
import requests

praser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Check domain for availability")
praser.add_argument("domain", type=str, help="Domain name to be checked")
args = praser.parse_args()

api_key = "API_KEY"
api_secret = "API_SECRET"
req_headers = {
    "Authorization": f"sso-key {api_key}:{api_secret}",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}


def get_req_url(check_domain):
    return f"https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?domain={check_domain}"


def check_domain_availability(check_domain):
    print(f"Checking the availability of the domain {check_domain} ...")
    req_url = get_req_url(check_domain)
    req = requests.get(req_url, headers=req_headers)
    if req.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Couldn't get availability state of the domain {check_domain} - Status code {req.status_code}")
        return
    response = req.json()
    if response["Available"] == True:
        print(f"Domain {check_domain} is available for purchase")

    else:
        print(f"{time.strftime('%y-%m-D %H:%M')} - Domain {check_domain} is not available for purchase")


check_domain_availability(args.domain)
```

The error:

> usage: godaddy bot.py [-h] domain
> godaddy bot.py: error: the following arguments are required: domain

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use spaces in Python script filenames. Rename your file to `godaddy_bot.py` instead of `godaddy bot.py`.

Then run `python godaddy_bot.py somedomain.com` – the error message plainly tells you you need to give it the domain as an argument.

Comment: how to put the domain as an argument? excuse me but i'm still a beginner

Comment: By writing what I said on the command line. If you're running your program via some IDE or editor, consult its instructions.